# TypeError: fixture.debugElement.query for mat-option is null

Tags: angular-material, karma-jasmine

I am new to Angular and testing it using Karma. I am trying to get the instance of *mat-options* from the template to verify its text content. Unfortunately, I receive null error from Karma saying

> TypeError: optionDe is null in ...

Here is the test code:

```
// When option is selected to [1], set selected to that:
  it(
    'Should select Shoes Order Type: International',
    () => {
      const de: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
      const optionDe = de.query(By.css('mat-option'));
      const p: HTMLElement = optionDe.nativeElement;
      expect(p.textContent).toEqual(''); 
    }
  );
```

and here is the template code:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Order-Type:</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
        <mat-option
            *ngFor="let type of orderTypes"
            [value] = "type.name">
            {{ type.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Question:

How to properly get a reference of that `mat-option` or any field in the template so that I won't get null-pointer exceptions and use its properties on the test?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is. You did not initialize any data in the code you shared. Try something like this.

```
// When option is selected to [1], set selected to that:
it('Should select Shoes Order Type: International',
() => {
  // initialize the data in your component 
  fixture.component.orderTypes = [{name : 'opition1'}];
  const de: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
  const optionDe = de.query(By.css('mat-option'));
  const p: HTMLElement = optionDe.nativeElement;
  expect(p.textContent).toEqual(''); 
}
);
```

Make sure that you have MatSelectModule in your spec.ts describe section

```
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MatSelectModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
      ],
      declarations: declarations,
      providers: [
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
```

Comment: I tried mocking values in orderTypes[] as you suggested, but still returns the same result. What I'm trying to understand is why `const optionDe = de.query(By.css('mat-option'));` throws that null exception. Is the reason due to I am giving a wrong value in By.css({value})? If so, how can I get the instance of that mat-option template to get its text content?

Comment: `const p: HTMLElement = optionDe.nativeElement;` Base on your error, `optionDe` is the null value, because you don't have any elements with the 'mat-option' class on it.

Comment: I tried exchanging <mat-select> and <mat-option> tags to <select> and <option> tags, and apparently it worked. I think the reason is those tags are dependencies on my Component.

Comment: I think you have not included the `MatSelectModule` in your spec ts. beforeEach file. Can you please share that section?

Comment: @DragonKatol : are u using `fixture.detectChanges()`